# Views filter: Filter by number of field values

Tags: views, entities

Is there a way in Views to create a filter that shows nodes by number of values for a field? For example, to create a view of nodes, showing only those with two or more terms from a given vocabulary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you look if you have access for your designated field to the **"delta"** version of this field ?

This will do the trick.

If you don't, I'd advise to use **aggregate** and **COUNT** values of the field. Will work the same. Create a filter with that field, activate aggregation, count.